# Unity3d:Add a public script via inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am creating a game, which is a Novel game. I want to add a functionality where my friend can add a new dialogue on a character game object. To do that, I already created a main script that enqueue and dequeue all of what is written on the inspector. Two more scripts, one script is a class for creating a new properties on the inspector where my friend can write, the other script functionality is to patch it on the inspector itself. I decided to add a patcher to customize unity editor to add a button. All what is left is a function to add another class where in my friend can write another character name and sentences.

This is what it looks like on Unity Inspector:
[image]

Please Help.

**DialogueManager.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
  {
   private Queue<string> sentences; 
   public Text WrapperName;
   public Text WrapperContent;
   void Start()
   {
       sentences = new Queue<string>();
   }

   public void StartDialogue (Dialogue dialogue)
   {
       WrapperName.text = dialogue.name;
       sentences.Clear();

       foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
       {
           sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
       }

       DisplayNextSentence();
   }
   public void DisplayNextSentence()
   {
       if(sentences.Count == 0)
       {
           EndDialogue();
           return;
       }
       string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
       WrapperContent.text = sentence;
   }
   public void EndDialogue()
   {
       Debug.Log("dialogue Ended..");
   }
```

}

**Dialogue.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{
    public string name;
    [TextArea(3, 10)]
    public string[] sentences;
}
```

**StoryElement.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StoryElement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue dialogue;

    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
    }
}
```

**elementscriptpatcher.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
[CustomEditor(typeof(StoryElement))]
public class elementscriptpatcher : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();


        if(GUILayout.Button("Add another script"))
        {
            // I need to write a function for appending a class Dialogue on Dialogue.cs which was initialized on the StoryElement.
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking: `Dialogue` is not a component so what are you trying to achieve? If you need to add more dialogues you'll need a list or array of dialogues ... Currently there is oy one single dialogue so you can't add more dialogues there...?

Answer (score -1):

you can use [GameObject.AddComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html).

```
    if(GUILayout.Button("Add another script"))
    {
           gameObject.AddComponent<Dialogue>();
    }
```

EDIT : As @derHugo said in comments, we can't add a class that's base is not `Monobehaviour`. So you will require an `Access Class` to access `Dialogue.cs`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AccessClass : MonoBehaviour {

    public Dialogue mClassObject;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error. error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'GameObject.AddComponent<Dialogue>()'

Comment: Bro its `gameObject` not `GameObject`.

Comment: Assets\elementscriptpatcher.cs(14,4): error CS0103: The name 'gameObject' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Because your base class is `Editor`. Use this function in a script whose base class is `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: I tried to reconstruct via mono behavior with both base class, it seems like I got an error that the class that I'm referring to is not a game object neither a method.

Comment: @gameDev_Unity `Dialogue` is not a `MonoBehaviour` but a "normal" class -> you can't use `AddComponent`

Comment: @derHugo you are right sir. I didn't notice.Thanks.

Comment: Remove the blank `Start` and `Update` methods. Because they are magic methods, there is overhead in the magic, so if they don't do anything, don't have them.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Ink](https://www.inklestudios.com/ink/) for Unity, and author the dialogue as text files.